# elixir plug: correct way to get form data from a post request

Tags: elixir

I'm playing around with the [plug router](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/extra-readme.html#The-Plug-Router) and trying to read the body of a simple post request in my router:

The form

```
<form action="/create_item" method="post">
  <input type="text" value="whatever" name="name">
  <input type="number" value="99" name="age">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

My router

```
post("/create_item") do
  {:ok, data, _conn} = read_body(conn)
  send_resp(conn, 200, data)
end
```

If I submit my form, this will render `name=input-value` to the page, but then I would have to parse that string to just get the value. This smells the the wrong way to do it.

From my little experience with elixir, it seems like I should be doing something like pattern-matching on the `read_body(conn)` to pull out each `key: value` from my form, but I cannot find anything about this in the [plug docs](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/extra-readme.html). I tried digging through the phoenix source for ideas, but that's a bit beyond my elixir knowledge. Is there an obvious `parse_form_data/1` function that I'm missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Plug.Conn.read_body/1` just reads the body of the request, without parsing it. To parse the body, you usually want to use the [`Plug.Parsers`](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Parsers.html) plug, which reads and parses the body of the request based on its content type.

For example, if you plug it like this:

```
plug Plug.Parsers, parsers: [:urlencoded]
```

everywhere after that in the pipeline will have `conn.params` available.

Comment: thanks! once the params are parsed, is there a more elixirish way of assigning them each to variables rather than just doing `name = conn.params["name"]` for each param?

Comment: @user2936314 nothing more concise than `name = conn.params["name"]` if you don't want to bring dependencies in. Otherwise, you can use [the short_maps library](https://github.com/whatyouhide/short_maps), which provides the `~m` sigil for doing something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
conn = parse(conn)
name = conn.params["name"]
age = conn.params["age"]

def parse(conn, opts \\ []) do
    opts = Keyword.put_new(opts, :parsers, [Plug.Parsers.URLENCODED, Plug.Parsers.MULTIPART])
    Plug.Parsers.call(conn, Plug.Parsers.init(opts))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I came across this question. That is the way I used:

```
{:ok, body, conn} = Plug.Conn.read_body(conn)
parsed_body = Poison.Parser.parse!(body)
IO.puts "The body is #{parsed_body}, #{inspect is_map(parsed_body))"
```

I think maybe another way to solve, so now I am reading Plug module doc.